# How can I avoid my UITextView from being covered by my UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uiviewanimation

I have created a forum with a View, and in the View I have placed a Text Field. My problem is, whenever I slide up they keyboard the text from the tableView are placed over the UIView and the TextField being covered. Any Idea what the reason behind this might be? While we are at it, maybe I shouldnt create a View with a TextField and instead use the standard look in iPhone sms apps, but I dont know how they created that bar. Any Ideas? I post all pictures below:

iPhone standard look, how to create something like this?: [image: http://oi46.tinypic.com/4zssbk.jpg]

My View with the text field: [image: http://oi47.tinypic.com/313kleu.jpg]

My problem as i described above: [image: http://oi50.tinypic.com/fz5atf.jpg]

Comment: Did you create your textfield with clear color? Are you moving your UIView along with textfield?

Comment: Frist question: no. 2nd question yes :S

Comment: did you use TableViewController or ViewController ?

Comment: Check my answer for your question as 'how they created that bar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom view for that and add it as an `inputAccessoryView` of the keyboard. 
For more details please check [apple documentation on this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html). When the keyboard is dismissed, show this view at bottom of the screen and when keyboard appears remove it from bottom and make it as inputAccessoryView.

> **inputAccessoryView:**
>
> The custom accessory view to display when the text view becomes the
>   first responder

Comment: While we are at it, how do I get those colors on the UIView as the standard look in sms apps? When you are refering to inputAccessoryView I guess you are refering to the send button on the View?. I am more after the looks and color. My UIView is not that stylish and uses fades/shadows in the same way...

Comment: inputAccessoryView represents the whole bar not just the send button. Either you can add this bar as a background image in UIView + custom buttons with custom background images + textfield.